# Bypass a form in VBA and continue macro

Tags: excel, vba

When I open files in my macro I get a box popup saying "this workbook contains links to other data sources etc." and then prompts me to select "update" "don't update" or "help". I want the macro to select "don't update" close it or skip it. How would I do this using VBA. I just want to continue and not have this stop the macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the Macro Recorder and checking the resulting code is helpful for things like this. If you do that I think you'll see something along the lines of:

```
workbooks.Open FileName:="MyWorkbook",UpdateLinks:=False
```